# sql sub query with max(datetime)

Tags: sql-server

I have a table dbo.counters with columns idx, idx_device, DateTime, Data1, Data2 etc.

- idx is key and autoincremental
- idx_device refers to another table, hundreds of rows may exists in table with same idx_device value
- DateTime is TimeStamp when record has been written

I need to have from each idx_device one complete row which is closest to a specific DateTime, but not higher than.

I got already following formula, but this does not output all columns from table:

```
select max(DateTime), idx_device from dbo.counters 
    WHERE DateTime <= '02/04/12 23:59:59.995' 
    group by idx_device
```

guess should be something small, but I hang... thanks

Comment: Please show table structure, sample data, and desired results. I liked word problems in school but they're not that fun when trying to solve business problems. Also, I strongly suggest you say `< '20120204'` rather than trying to find the "end of day" - and avoid formats like m/d/y or d/m/y - why? Because I can't even tell if that's February 4 or April 2 (or maybe year isn't even the last number).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using [Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx):

```
with cte as
    (select 
        *, 
        row_number() 
        over (partition by idx_device order by DateTime desc) as rowno
    from dbo.Counters
    where DateTime < '2012-02-04')
select * from cte where rowno = 1
```

Comment: Good stuff, you just beat me to the punch! Removing mine... +1

Answer (score 0):

The following should give you what you want:

```
SELECT * 
FROM    dbo.Counters C
INNER JOIN
      (SELECT idx_device, 
              MAX(DateTime) AS MaxDateTime
      FROM    dbo.Counters
      WHERE  DateTime < '20120205'
      GROUP BY idx_device) AS MaxCounters 
        ON C.idx_device = MaxCounters.idx_device AND C.DateTIme = MaxCounters.MaxDateTime
```

You are right in that you need to group your records by device id to get the max date time. Once we have those, we join back onto the parent table to retrieve the records with the same device id **and also** have that datetime.

Note that if you have multiple device id combos with the same time, you might want to consider using DISTINCT.

Comment: thats it - works perfectly - just have to add one day programmatically to datetime to get results also of the same day

thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
DECLARE @CompareDate Datetime
SET @CompareDate =  '02/04/12 23:59:59.995'

;WITH c AS 
(
    SELECT *, rowrank = row_number() over(partition by idx_device order by DateTime desc)
    FROM dbo.Counters
    WHERE DateTime < @CompareDate
)
SELECT * FROM c WHERE rowrank = 1
```